# minted linebreak in framebox

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, minted, code

I have a code snippet that I highlight with minted.
The problem is that one line is too long, and goes out of the frame box.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{minted}[
        frame=single,
        obeytabs=true,
        tabsize=4,
        linenos,
        breaklines,
        numbersep=6pt
    ]{json}
    "example":[
        [
            {
                "info": "dummy",
                "data": "kfudshfdsifdshfpodsfwe8jrpw4r9wjkfwpeofreagpaergfasdfdsfdsfdsfffskdfjpdsifkdspfodsfsdf",
                "version": "latest"
            },
        ]
    ]
    \end{minted}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

The line break seems not to be sufficient, as it still goes out of bounds.
How can I add proper line breaks and formatting ? I assume multiple line breaks are needed when the data is that long?

Comment: You can use `breakanywhere`. But the code doesn't seem to be valid JSON syntax.

Comment: @egreg It's valid - but its just a part of the entire json document that I like to display. Also I am still having the same problem with breakanywhere..? Am I missing something?

Comment: @egreg Hm, I think I got it now. I need to have both, `breaklines` and `breakanywhere` defined. Not the most pretty solution but I don't think there is a better way?